# How to get Entity class name by relation name

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have 2 Entities **City** and **Region**
City linked to Region this way:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Region", inversedBy="cities")
 * @var Region
 */
protected $region;
```

How can I get Region class name having only "region" string (and knowing that region is a relation of `City`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the entity/object manager (`\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager`) you can call `getClassMetadata($className)`.

E.g.:

```
$metaData = $em->getClassMetadata(City::class);
$metaData->getAssociationTargetClass('region'); // => 'Region'
```